# Add shading effect to DIV element using SVG

Tags: html, svg

Is it possible to have a normal div with a black border, but for newer browsers add various shading effects using SVG?

I.e. The border will show for older browsers, but for newer browsers you might have a shadow that make the div appear to be a sheet of paper that is lifted.

**EDIT: Image sample**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything ? You might take a look at [svg filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html) but I think that you could achieve that with css too.

Comment: It's an intricate shadow making two of the corners appear lifted. We've tried this before with CSS, but we never get a great affect

Comment: Show a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see exactly what you need.

Comment: I edited my question and added a screenshot. We achieved this in another project but we were forced to use background images. The problem with this approach is that if you then add more content to the block you have to resize and recut the image.

Answer (score 2):

I actually managed to solve this using Craig Buckler's approach at the following link: 
http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-paper-curls/

This approach basically uses :before and :after pseudo classes positioned behind the div. They do make use of box-shadow effects as well as transforms.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="note">
    <div class="note-shadow-top">
        <div class="note-shadow-bottom">
            <div class="note-content">
                <asp:Literal ID="ContentLiteral" Text="Content" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.note
{
}

.note-content
{
    padding: 20px;
}

.note p:last-child
{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.note-shadow-top
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: #fff;

    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

    .note-shadow-top:before, .note-shadow-top:after
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 40%;
        height: 40%;
        content: ' ';
        left: 4px;
        top: 11px;
        background: transparent;
        -webkit-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(1deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(1deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(1deg);
        -o-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(1deg);
        transform: skew(5deg) rotate(1deg);
        -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: -4px 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: -4px 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .note-shadow-top:after
    {
        left: auto;
        right: 4px;
        -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(1deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(1deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(1deg);
        -o-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(1deg);
        transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(1deg);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 4px 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 4px 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }


.note-shadow-bottom
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

    .note-shadow-bottom:before, .note-shadow-bottom:after
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 40%;
        height: 10px;
        content: ' ';
        left: 0;
        bottom: 8px;
        background: transparent;
        -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-7deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-7deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-7deg);
        -o-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-7deg);
        transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-7deg);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .note-shadow-bottom:after
    {
        left: auto;
        right: 1px;
        -webkit-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
        -o-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
        transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
    }
.ie8 .note-shadow-top, .ie7 .note-shadow-top
{
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
}
```

Hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

shadow effects can be achieved by means of the css3 `box-shadow` attribute. some examples can be found [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) and [this Site](http://css3generator.com/) allows for interactive Generation of the CSS Clauses with immediate preview (Other css effects also).

example file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>css3 box shadow demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:500px; height:100px; -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;">no content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input collapsar, but we've tried box-shadows and they can't produce the affect we're looking for. I've edited my post and added a screenshot of the effect we're trying to achieve.